# Linux_How to enable cookies for specific site in firefox using command line

Tags: linux, firefox, cookies, command-line, fedora12

I have application embedded in Firefox and it is installed on **Linux(Fedora)** machine. We have disabled cookies and other user controls (Right click, menu access etc.) 
Now there is one site which continuously prompts below Cookies message

> **This website uses cookies**
>
> This website uses cookies and similar technologies to offer you an
>   optimal user experience. Functional cookies are necessary for the
>   proper functioning of the website. we only place the other cookies if
>   you give permission. If you do not want it, turn the sliders to the
>   left. The other cooks give you an optimal user experience. Do you want
>   to know how we deal with privacy? see our privacy statement.

This is only case with single website. So can you please tell me how to handle this cookies condition **using command line**? OR how to enable cookies for this single website? Where should I add condition to accept cookies for this website?

Thanks for solution.
Mrunal

Comment: Anyone have solution for this?